# How to use 3D Touch to achieve sharing like this?

Tags: ios

I found that many of the app using 3D Touch to call UIActivityController to share, I search a lot of content are not found to explain, I hope someone can help me to solve, thank you.
[image: step1]
[image: step2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3D Touch iOS 10 Home screen quick actions share Item missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39752216/swift-3d-touch-ios-10-home-screen-quick-actions-share-item-missing)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I actually asked that question the other day as well.

[Swift 3D Touch iOS 10 Home screen quick actions share Item missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39752216/swift-3d-touch-ios-10-home-screen-quick-actions-share-item-missing)

This is a new iOS 10 feature that all apps got by default, so there is nothing you will have to do. 
You will only see it on the version thats live on the app store, it will not show up when you are testing.

Answer (score -1):

There is one solution for it to resolve use the cyclomatic library of force touhc and it will do the work for you