# Swift 3D Touch iOS 10 Home screen quick actions share Item missing

Tags: swift, ios10, 3dtouch

In my apps that use 3D touch home screen quick actions I do not have the new iOS 10 default sharing option that all apps got for free.

I have seen some apps, for example Amazon, that have their 4 custom shortcut items (quick actions) and the 1 default sharing option.

Is there a way I can get the default iOS 10 sharing option back?

Comment: Is your app in the App Store?

Comment: Hey thanks, I was just about to post an answer. I did not realise it only shows up on the live app store app and not in testing. If you want to post a quick answer I will mark it for you!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

That feature or option is only available for apps that are live on the App Store, it will not show up when testing your app. It is done automatically so there is nothing you will have to do.

Comment: so if I need "Share" action appear along with my 2 custom 3d touch actions, it means that I just need to declare 2 custom actions in the plist and when application will be live on the appstore, "Share" action will appear by itself? could you give a link to documentation describing this behavior?

Comment: Correct you only need to add your custom 3d touch actions.  The "Share - App Name"  is built into the iOS and is now automatic once the app is published in the App Store.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Ben Correct no code required to share the app just needs to be live in the App Store.